# bootstrap align img same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have the IMG aligned on the same line using bootstrap how to do it? I am quite junior.

Is it necessary to define col-12 below the row?

```css
img {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let img of lstImg">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="img != 'tImg'; else elseBlock">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" #elseBlock>
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "line", you're meaning row ? Or column ?

Comment: You've got a type error in your code, missing `=` in `class"col-sm-3"`

Comment: @Pof i mean row yes

Comment: You can vertically align your cols by adding `.align-items-center` to your `.row`. If you want to horizontally center your cols, you should use a row wrapper for each cols, and use `.mx-auto` on you cols

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want... here is a working example : https://codepen.io/pof/pen/oNwZOoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Contain two different sized images on the same row (Option 1)

The Bootstrap way... Adding `.img-fluid` class to the images applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; so that they scale with the parent element.

```css
img {
  height: 15rem;
}

.row {
  background: #e3e3e3; /* let's visualise the row */
}

.row div[class^='col'] {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let img of lstImg">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="img != 'tImg'; else elseBlock">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" #elseBlock>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Contain two different sized images on the same row (Option 2)

Adding `object-fit: contain;` allows the images to fill their container. We'll also need to remove the `.img-fluid` class

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.row {
  background: #e3e3e3; /* let's visualise the row */
}

.row div[class^='col'] {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let img of lstImg">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="img != 'tImg'; else elseBlock">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" #elseBlock>
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Images fill their container

Changing to `object-fit: cover;` allows the images to fill their container.

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.row {
  background: #e3e3e3; /* let's visualise the row */
}

.row div[class^='col'] {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let img of lstImg">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="img != 'tImg'; else elseBlock">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" #elseBlock>
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tv-test-image-card-rainbow-multi-color-bars-geometric-signals-retro-hardware-s-minimal-pop-art-print-suitable-89603635.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info on the CSS object-fit Property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp).